# How to execute a subprocess with multithreading

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This program works and displays server latency on a small canvas, but because it takes the program time to ping the server and display the ping `def display():`, it is not possible to drag the window `class WindowDraggable():`, until the subprocess has finished, and thus there is lag when dragging the window. Can this lag be resolved with mutil-threading so the window can be dragged smoothly?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import subprocess
import _thread

host = "141.101.115.212" #host IP address

root = Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)
im = Image.open("image.png")
width, height = im.size
canvas = Canvas(root, width=width, height=height)
canvas.pack()
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="image.png")
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=image, anchor=NW)
text = canvas.create_text(125, 75, anchor=CENTER)

def display():
    global text
    #Launches 'command' windowless and waits until finished; finds ping
    suinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    suinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    x = subprocess.Popen(["ping.exe", "141.101.115.212"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=suinfo)
    #find latency with regex
    x = str(x.communicate()[0])
    lhs, rhs = x.split("Average = ")
    lhs, rhs = rhs.split("\\", 1)
    lhs, rhs = lhs.split("m")
    if int(lhs) > 999:
        lhs = "999" + "ms"
    latency = lhs
    canvas.itemconfig(text, text=latency, width=width)
    canvas.itemconfig(text, font=("courier", 25, "bold"))
    canvas.itemconfig(text, fill="white")
    root.after(1000, display)


class WindowDraggable():

    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label
        label.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.StartMove)
        label.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.StopMove)
        label.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.OnMotion)

    def StartMove(self, event):
        self.x = event.x
        self.y = event.y

    def StopMove(self, event):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None

    def OnMotion(self,event):
        x = (event.x_root - self.x - self.label.winfo_rootx() + self.label.winfo_rootx())
        y = (event.y_root - self.y - self.label.winfo_rooty() + self.label.winfo_rooty())
        root.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x, y))

label = Label(root, text='drag me')
WindowDraggable(label)
label.pack()
#_thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-2", 4, ) )
root.after(0, display())
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why not just wait until the process is actually finished before you try communicating with it?

Comment: @WayneWerner I am still a bit new to Python (and programming in general), and I'm not sure what you mean. Could you please illustrate your suggestion as an answer?

Comment: @WayneWerner I am still lost...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try to fight Tkinter's builtin loop/threading, use it:

```
def wait_for_it(proc):
    proc.poll()
    if proc.returncode is None:                      # subprocess hasn't finished yet
        root.after(100, lambda: wait_for_it(proc))   # register a callback for 100ms
    else:
        display(proc.communicate()[0])


def display(x):
    lhs, rhs = x.split("Average = ")
    # the rest of your code goes here...

# instead of root.after(0, display)
wait_for_it(subprocess.Popen(['ping', 'google.com']))
```

As a slight aside, I highly recommend pasting your code on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange to get some style pointers and help simplifying it.

Comment: Thanks, what exactly are the differences between the two sites? Is the former aimed more towards help on entire programs as opposed to malfunctioning snippets?

Comment: This site was originally a bit more encompassing. As we got larger and larger we needed to continually narrow and refine the scope. So now some things that may have been quasi on topic are either less or completely off topic. SO is more of an error driven site - something doesn't work but I don't know why. CR is really for when you have code that is functional, but could be improved in ways that maybe the computer doesn't care about - but other programmers will. SO is more fact checking, where CR is more editing. At least that's my understanding!